# Symfony2 Form Builder PRE_SET_DATA Convert Datetime to String Date

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, formbuilder

I have a datetime field and i'm using jquery datepicker to select date with in a text field
(input[type=text).

When i want to create a new record, there is no problem. When i want to edit that record, i have to set datetime data as text date format (Y-m-d) and print to text field.

My field (in orm.yml):

```
released_at:
  type: datetime
  nullable: true
```

My form builder:

```
$builder->add(
    'releasedAt',
        null,
        [
            'label' => 'Çıkış Tarihi',
            'mapped' => false, // false because setting the datetime data in the controller
            'attr' => ['class' => 'date-picker']
        ]
);
```

My form pre_set_data:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $game = $event->getData();

        if ($game instanceof Game) {
            $datetime = $game->getReleasedAt();
            $form->get('releasedAt')->setData(\Datetime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $datetime->format('Y-m-d')));
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
```

Error:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class DateTime. You
>   can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "DateTime"
>   or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   DateTime to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.

What is the problem here?

---- Edit ----

I have also tried this:

```
$builder->add(
        'releasedAt',
        'datetime',
        [
            'label' => 'Çıkış Tarihi',
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'date_format'=>'y-M-d',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'date-picker']
        ]
    )
```

But the view is showing the time selections and wraps all fields with a div.

I don't want to edit datetime form view.

First option is better for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Solution is simple.

When we look at this diagram:

[image]

Just change the PRE_SET_DATA to POST_SET_DATA.

Code:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $game = $event->getData();

    if($game === null || $game->getId() === null)
        return;

    if ($game instanceof Game) {
        $datetime = $game->getReleasedAt();
        $form->get('releasedAt')->setData($game->getReleasedAt()->format('Y-m-d'));
    }
});
```

Comment: what does mean "normalization" in the diagram?